# Chart not visible while creating report using Visualize.js

Tags: visualization, jasperserver, visualize

I am using visualize.js to render  jasper reports, am getting report with images but its not showing the charts. Given below is my code

```
visualize({
  server:"http://************/reportservice",
  auth:{
  name:"*****",
  password:"****"
 }
},function(v){
   var report=v.report({
   server:"http://***********/reportservice",
   resource:"/organizations/Organization*******Projectboard3",
   container:"#container",
});
report.params({
   "projectKey_2":"5001082",
})
 report.run();
},function(err){
  alert(err.message);
}
);
```

Do i need to include any js other than Visualize.js to render the charts. Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, we need to give parameters as array like

```
{["projectKey_2":"5001082"]}
```